# Помощь с регуляркой

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Нужен замена подстроки **'5п -Б' на 'Больше'**

'цифра от 0-9'п-(1 пробел)М' сменить на 'Меньше'

'цифра от 0-9'п-(1 пробел)Б' сменить на 'Больше'

Эти 2 условия можно запилить 1 регуляркой?

Comment: Это чисто спортивный интерес? Потому что с точки зрения программы две или три регулярки ничуть не хуже одной.

Comment: не спортивный интерес а работа....Помню про М|Б а вот как запомнить выбор не помню.

Comment: Можно, вместо строки замены передайте в replace функцию-callback. Можно без callback, но регулярное выражение будет очень извращенное.

Comment: Если работа, воспользуйтесь тремя регулярками.

Comment: Будет намного производительней?

Comment: @koza4ok, производительней будет каллбаком нежели тремя выражениями, если у Вас текст размером пару десятков мегабайт, то производительнее будет одним извращенным регулярным выражением.

Comment: <цитата о преждевременной оптимизации>

Сначала добейтесь того, чтобы программа работала правильно и начальство приняло задание, потом найдите самый тормознутый кусок (профилируйте!) и отоптимизируйте его (если, конечно, будет свободное время и желание).

Answer (score 3):

**Вариант А:** на **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/KxbHB/3/)**

```
var replacement = {
    'Б': 'больше',
    'М': 'меньше'
};

function replacer(match, p1){
  return replacement[p1];
};

var string = '4 5п -М 5, 5 1п -Б 4\r\n2 0п -Б 1';
console.log(string.replace(/[0-9]п \-(М|Б)/g, replacer));

//4 больше 5, 5 меньше 4
//2 меньше 1
```

**Вариант Б:** на **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/KxbHB/1/)**.

```
var subject = {},
    subject.modify = function (pattern, replacement, str) {
        for (var key in pattern) {
            str = str.replace(pattern[key], replacement[key]);
        }
        return str;
    };

pattern = {
    'b': /[0-9]п \-Б/g,
    's': /[0-9]п \-М/g
};
replacement = {
    'b': 'больше',
    's': 'меньше'
};

var string = '4 5п -Б 5, 5 1п -М 4\r\n2 0п -М 1';
console.log(subject.modify(pattern, replacement, string));

//4 больше 5, 5 меньше 4
//2 меньше 1
```

Comment: Спасибо.Потестим.

Comment: Исправил соотнесение ключей и значений в replacement.

Answer (score 2):

2 из ХХХХ возможных [варианта](http://ideone.com/h6mqDM).

Comment: А js принимает массив выражений?...